# How can I install file-roller for CentOS 6 to use in Gnome?

Tags: centos, gnome, software-installation

I've just started messing about with Linux and trying to figure things out as I go using tutorials. I've installed Gnome desktop and have some .rar files I would like to open.

I've found `file-roller` which looks really good but I can't find any simple guides on how to install it.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for getting file-roller to run on my gnome desktop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrar tool can help you to extract these rar files on redhat linux.
This might alreay install on your linux box, open terminal and type `unrar`
If not You can install it thru

```
#yum install unrar
```

You can also follow [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-rar-file-or-extract-rar-files-under-linux-or-unix/)

To install file-roller

```
yum install file-roller
```

you can launch `file-roller` by typing it on terminal, when interface comes up, use open and point your rar archive –

Comment: I have rar and unrar installed already, But i wanted something to use in desktop which has a GUI.

Comment: you can launch `file-roller` by typing it on terminal, when interface comes up, use open and point your `rar` archive

Answer (score 1):

Download file-roller rpm for centos 6 from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20338851/dir/centos_6/com/file-roller-2.28.2-6.el6.i686.rpm.html)
Then execute the command:

`rpm -ivh file-roller-2.28.2-6.el6.i686.rpm`

Comment: I get a very long list of missing dependencies do i have to install them all 1 by 1?